# Are humans more aggressive during a full moon?

Tags: physiology, behaviour

Is it true that we are more agressive during the night when there is a full moon?
If true, could this be a remnant from times where we needed to hunt for our food and so could see more at night when there was a full moon?

Source of question: [article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1553652/More-police-to-patrol-on-full-moons.html)

Comment: Umm, what gives you that idea? Could you provide a reference?

Comment: added an article

Comment: newspapers say such things all the time.. there is not much credibility..

Comment: thats why I asked if it was a myth or true story :D

Comment: This is more fit for Skeptics and has already been asked there. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/948/are-more-crimes-committed-during-a-full-moon/949#949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a piece of *pseudoscience* commonly seen these days. The truth is that *this effect has never been statistically observed*.

From the [Skeptics Stack Exchange site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/948/are-more-crimes-committed-during-a-full-moon/949#949):

> Ivan Kelly, James Rotton and Roger Culver (1996) examined over 100 studies on lunar effects and concluded that the studies have failed to show a reliable and significant correlation (i.e., one not likely due to chance) between the full moon, or any other phase of the moon, and each of the following: The homicide rate, traffic accidents, crisis calls to police or fire stations, domestic violence, assassinations, kidnappings, aggression by professional hockey players, violence in prisons, assaults, gunshot wounds, stabbings

... and many more seen [here](http://www.skepdic.com/fullmoon.html).